# What is chrome window controls bar in Android's material design?

Tags: android, material-design

When reading Google's new guideline on material design, I found a part mentioning "Chrome window bar". Here's the link and pics: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-system-bars

[image: Chrome window bar]

[image: Chrome window bar on top of the app bar]

[image: Chrome window controls inside app bar]

I am using Lollipop and Chrome browser but never find that Chrome window controls anywhere. This raise several related questions:

- What is it exactly? Where is it used? Is there any Google's app using it?
- Can we use it in our own project? Is there any official documentation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has embedded the Materials design spec into the Chrome OS.  You can run android apps inside of Chrome browser and there are now android apps specifically for Chrome OS.

The part where you read about the menu bar, that is for apps written for chrome.  Instead of two menu bars, the chrome one is hidden and its functions are incorporated into the android action/menu bar.   At least that is how I understand it.  Google is selling a laptop called the chromebook with the OS.

http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/09/first-set-of-android-apps-coming-to.html

http://lifehacker.com/the-first-android-apps-are-now-available-for-chrome-os-1633549691